# Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

hey everyone I'm having this error (MEAN STACK)

- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
- Parameter "filter" to find() must be an object, got 1984"

**This is the backend code:**

```js
    booksRoute.route('/:name').get((req,res,next)=>{
        BookModel.find(req.params.name,(error,data)=>{
            if (error){
                return next(error) ; 
            } else {
                res.json(data)
            }
        })
    })
```

just a simple API to get a book by it's name that's all
and here's the frontend code (form with one single input for the book name)

```html
    <form  method="GET" class="d-flex" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="searchBook(f.value)">
    <input name="searchedBook" class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="search book by name" aria-label="Search" ngModel>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

and here's the service I'm using to get data

```js
    getBook(name){
        return this.http.get(this.backendUrl+'/'+name) ; 
      }
```

and here's the mongoose data model

```js
    let books = new Schema({
        name:{
            type:String
        },
        genre:{
            type:String
        },
        author:{
            type:String
        },
        rating:{
            type:Number
        },
        price:{
            type:Number
        }
    },{
        collection: 'booklist' 
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass object with property `name` to the `.find()`, and you have passed `req.params.name`. Change your code like this:

```js
BookModel.find({ name: req.params.name },(error,data)=>{
```

Comment: yes, thank you so much but can u explain to me what's the difference ? i mean find() takes a string and a callback function as paramaters and that's what i did i think. so why should i add this {name: xxx} ?

Comment: It does not take string, it takes object. The object's `key` should be the name of the property that you are filtering, and the object's `value` should be the value that you are filtering.